# Adding links to an email message

Tags: android

I was wondering if it is possible to hook into the gmail and email
applications and check to see if it contains text that matches a
regular expression, and if it does, make that text into a link with a
URI that would open my application. What i am thinking of is similar
to how the gmail application can detect a web address or phone number
and make it a link. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail app is closed source and you only have the hooks they give you.  AFAIK regular-expression-to-hyperlink-conversion isn't one of them:

[Extending Android's Default Gmail/Email Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926770/extending-androids-default-gmail-email-applications)

Depending on what you're doing, you might be able to send mail through some kind of gateway which does this work on the message prior to delivery.  So rather than emailing johndoe@gmail.com people could write to johndoe@example.com, and the work of translating phrases into URIs could be done at example.com then forwarded to gmail.com with links in place...

But people are link-savvy these days.  You can make links plenty readable, for instance look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL ...fairly obvious, no magic required and I can enter that even without Google's help.